# How to set the protocol (http, ws etc.) for the end-point using Jinja2 & url_for

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to use the `url_for(...)` function in Python/Jinja2 to create an end-point for a web-socket.

How can I tell `url_for(...)` inside my template to use the 'ws' (web socket) protocol instead of 'http'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.url_for) has two attributes you can use for this purpose:

- `_external = True` for generating absolute URLs
- `_scheme = ''` for setting an empty URL scheme (`ws` or `wss` is not supported directly)

After that, just put the `ws:` or `wss:` URL scheme string just before the `url_for` call in your template, e.g.:

```
wss:{{ url_for('websocket_endpoint', _external=True, _scheme='') }}
```

which will produce:

```
wss://yourdomain.com/websocket_endpoint
```